# Any simple Digital All-Pass Filter Design Tools?

Tags: filter-design

I would like to be able to implement an All-Pass filter with a frequency-dependent group delay.  I need a maximum group delay at low frequency of about 20 samples (for F*s* = 44.1kHz), and it needs to fall to zero(-ish) at the Nyquist frequency.  Ideally, I would like to specify a corner frequency and a rate at which the delay falls off either side of it.  How the heck would I design such a thing?

I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently competent to follow the design approaches I can find on the web that plunge straight into poles, zeros, transfer functions and complex conjugates.  What I can do, though, is implement the darned thing efficiently in code once it is designed.

I am able to use Matlab to design FIR and IIR low-pass filters, because it has a built-in tool that spits them out.  But it doesn't have an All-Pass filter design tool (at least not one I can find).

Comment: Well as far as I know there aren't much tools because the common design for an all-pass filter is pretty simple. However, following the equation from Wikipedia might help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter

Comment: I didn't see anything that looks "pretty simple" there :(

Comment: Did you try using [this](http://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dfilt.allpass.html) Matlab function?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I don't see how to get from my baseline requirements (group delay vs frequency) to where I can make use of this function.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excerpt from the FilterScript user's guide, which should provide you with enough information on how to design the filter. Please refer to the other product resources on [the tool's homepage for more information.](http://www.advsolned.com/asn_filter_designer.html)

[image: FilterScript code for a second order all-pass filter]

Comment: Thanks, but you should have edited your other question.  I've deleted your other answer and included the link to your website here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll bear that in mind next time.